# How to make hidden divs visible using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, hidden-field

I am testing an application where I have to click a menu button, which displays a set of menu options. I have to click on one of the menu options to navigate a page. The sample HTML code is as follows.

```
<custom-icon icon="AngleDown"></custom-icon>
<div class = "options" hidden="hidden">
<div class="optionItems"> Settings </div>
</div>
```

Here, If i click on the custom icon(a button), the hidden options div becomes visible and I can click on the Settings div to navigate to a page. But as the options div is hidden, I am not able to access it. Could anyone please help me with this. My main motive of flow is to click on the Settings button (which is in the hidden div) and navigate to another page

I have tried clicking on the custom-icon and clicking on the Settings div. I am getting an element not clickable error. I'm guessing that clicking on the custom-icon is not making the options div visible.

Comment: You can remove the hidden attribute of your div tag to make it visible

Comment: I cannot make changes to the HTML code. Can I make it somehow visible using selenium webdriver?

Comment: You can use findelementBbyxpath to get the element. And you can remove the attribute from it. Can you please post your class?

Comment: I already gave the class for both the divs right? One is “options”  and other is “optionItems”